# How can i add active class in first div using *ngFor in angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have `carousel-item` divs those are repeating through `*ngFor` now I want to add `active` class in the first `div (carousel-item)`. How can I addClass in angular 7?

component.html

```
 <div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let testimonial of getTestimonial">
       <p>{{testimonial.description}}</p>
        <p class="font-weight-bold font-italic t-name">{{testimonial.name}} - {{testimonial.profession}}</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let testimonial of getTestimonial; let isFirst = first"  [class.active]="isFirst">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div class="carousel-item" [class.active]="i===0" *ngFor="let testimonial of getTestimonial; let i=index">
      // your stuff ..
  </div>
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-78jvq8?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let testimonial of getTestimonial;let i=index" [ngClass]="{'active': i == 0}">
   <p>{{testimonial.description}}</p>
    <p class="font-weight-bold font-italic t-name">{{testimonial.name}} - {{testimonial.profession}}</p>
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **ngClass** something like this:

```
<div  class="carousel-item" 
      [ngClass]="{'active': isFirst }" 
      *ngFor = "let testimonial  of getTestimonial; let isFirst = first;">
        {{testimonial.title}}  {{testimonial.description}}
</div>
```